# What does the return line do?

Tags: java, return, this

I have the class Estado, as:

```
public class Estado implements Comparable {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    .
    .
    .


    public boolean equals(Object x) {
        Estado e = (Estado) x;
        return this.x==e.x && this.y==e.y;
    }
}
```

What does the line

> return this.x==e.x && this.y==e.y;

do?

Comment: What is `==`? What is `&&`? (Hint: they are called operators. Look them up.)

Comment: it evaluates this expression and results in a boolean value and return computed value

Comment: print it and you will know what it returns

Comment: it's also important to note that you should be able to tell what a function return is by looking at what the functions declaration's expected return is Hence "public boolean equals(*){}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`return ...;`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) means "evaluate `...` and exit the function, making the resulting value the function's return value."

So let's break it down:

```
this.x==e.x
```

`==` is an [*equality operator*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21). That line checks to see if `this.x` is equal to `e.x` (and `this.y==e.y` does the same for the `y`s).

Let's call the result of the `x` check `xResult` and the result of the `y` check `yResult`.

Next, we have `&&`:

```
xResult && yResult
```

`&&` is a boolean "AND" operator (the spec calls it a ["Conditional-And operator"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23)): It's `true` if both of its operands are `true`, `false` if either of them is `false`.

So the function will return `true` if both conditions are true, `false` if either condition is false.

---

Side note: As [chrylis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis) points out in a comment, there's another way the function could terminate: Something called an [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html). The first line of the function, `Estado e = (Estado) x;`, might "throw" (cause) an exception if the argument passed into the function does refer to an object, but the object isn't an `Estado` object (so the "cast" `(Estado)x` is invalid); the line you asked about might throw an exception if the argument passed into the function is `null` (doesn't refer to any object). When an exception is thrown within a function and not "caught" by code in the function, the function stops running but not via a `return` statement.

Comment: Or throw an exception if the cast fails or the argument is null.

Comment: @chrylis: Quite true. The cast part isn't on the line the OP asked about, but you're right of course that `e.x` will throw a `NullPointerException` if `e` is `null` (which it could be if the argument is `null`).